# How do I use a .NET DLL in an ASP Classic website?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, asp-classic

This ASP Classic website requires a certain functionality. I have found a .NET library that supplies this functionality. I have a DLL file for this library.

The website has several ASPX files in the web directory (**EDIT**: alongside many ASP files). I'm not sure how that works. Some of them have directives at the top like `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>`; none of them seem to have any non-`System` namespaces listed. I've written another ASPX file with a directive saying `<%@ Assembly Src="path/to/MyLibrary.dll" %>`, but it returned an error message:

> **Parser Error Message:** There is no build provider registered for the extension '.dll'. You can register one in the  section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.

I've looked through several Stack Overflow answers and haven't been able to figure out what I have to do to use this library. Some of them seem to assume the website is something built in Visual Studio. Other answers and linked pages talk about COM Callable Wrappers or the Global Assembly Cache. My understanding of IIS in general seems to be way short of where it's supposed to be.

I *think* there's a strategy for using the DLL in an ASP file separate from using it in an ASPX file. Either would work for me, but I've already written the ASP.NET code.

Comment: Have you read these: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxz80y2.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285.aspx

Comment: Are you sure it's ASP Classic? Are there .ASP files laying around? Or just .ASPX?

Comment: It's mostly .ASP files. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Have you tried to develop a .dll COM+ Object for Interop? I usually develop it in C# and after that i register it on the server, so i can call it in any classic asp pages using set myobject = server.createobject("MyObject.Myclass")